# How to validate a string if it contain this char?

Tags: javascript

I make a scrip to validate if a string contain some char. But, I have a problem with this string.

This is my script:

```
var special_char  = ['|', '/', '&', ' ', '$', '@', ';', '*', '%', '.', ','];
var file_name_ext = upl_data.substring(upl_data.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, upl_data.length);
var file_name     = file_name_ext.split('.');               
var isVerified    = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < special_char.length; i++){                  
        if(file_name[0].indexOf(special_char[i]) == -1) {                       
            isVerified += 0;                     
        } else {
            isVerified += 1;
        }
    }

    if(isVerified != 0){
        alert("NOT OK");
    }
    else{ alert("OK"); }
```

Above script works well until I encounter this string:
`XXX.YYY.pdf`. Because I split using `.` and use `file_name[0]`, it ignores all the `special_char`.  How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Uh ... don't split on `.`?

Comment: Use [regular expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp).

Comment: We can also check that `indexOf('.') == lastIndexOf('.')` if not error

Comment: @melpomene i split using `.` to remove the file extension

Comment: @Vahn Why not validate the whole string, including the "extension"?

Comment: @melpomene extension validation is already created before the script. so if extension is valid move to next validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use following regular expression to get filename without extension:

```js
var file = 'xxx.yyy.pdf',
  filename = file.match(/.+(?=\.\w+$)/)[0];
console.log(filename);
```

But I think the best way is validate full filename using `test` method of `RegExp` object. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) says file names (including file extension) must not contain the following characters:

> The following reserved characters:
>
> - less than (<)
> - greater than (>)
> - colon (:)
> - double quote (")
> - forward slash (/)
> - backslash ( \ )
> - vertical bar or pipe (|)
> - question mark (?)
> - asterisk (*)

Thus, it is possible to use following regular expression to validate a file name for both NTFS and FAT file systems:

```js
var file = 'xxx.yyy.pdf',
  isValid = /^[^<>:"/\\?*]+$/.test(file);
console.log(isValid );
```

There is [online tool](https://regex101.com/) to help you.

Comment: Alexander, would you mind also explaining the above? Just interesting in a walk-through of this particular line of code - `/.+(?=\.\w+$)/`. Thanks!

Comment: @rishijd, the `(?= ... )` is zero-width positive lookahead assertion. So, the regular expression captures one or more any characters (`.+`) before substring that starts with period (`\.`), contains one or more digits or letters (`\w+`) and ends with end of string (`$`). See [JavaScript RegExp Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alexander - very clear and much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var file_name_ext = "XXX.YYY.pdf"
var file_name = file_name_ext.slice(0, file_name_ext.lastIndexOf('.'));

console.log(file_name)
```

Simple solution to trim extention